# How to configure my virtual host properly on Apache in Ubuntu?

Tags: apache, ubuntu

As the question says, I am trying to configure my virtual host on Apache in Ubuntu but I am getting some troubles. Here are the steps that I already done:

- I created a folder on `/var/rootfolder/host1.com/public` where `rootfolder` it is my default directory (instead of `/var/www`). I created an `index.html` file inside of `public` folder.
- After that I modify the file `hosts` on `/etc/` and add the following line:

  ```
                            MY IP host1.com
  ```
- Also I go to the folder `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and create the configuration of my new host. I named the file `host1.com.conf` and inside it I put:

`<VirtualHost MY IP:Port that it is listening>`

```
 ServerName host1.com
 ServerAlias www.host1.com
 ServerAdmin someone@host1.com
 DocumentRoot /var/rootfolder/host1.com/public
 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

- I activated the new host: `sudo a2ensite host1.com.conf`
- I reloaded Apache: `service apache2 reload`

but the problem I have it is that it is redirecting me to the page http://www.host1plus.com/ instead of the `.html` that I put on the folder `public`.

Am I missing some step? Is it my configuration in the correct way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried changing the name to something non existent on the internet like myveryownsiteyeah123.com just to troubleshoot? also if you ping host1.com is your local IP resolving?

Comment: @jotadepicas If I ping `host1.com` the same IP as I put on the VirtualHost is resolving it and no, I did not tried with another name.

Answer (score 0):

at first, you are trying to use a registered domain while i may believe you are not the owner of it.

Check what results you get when you ping your configured domain. Does it point to your server address, or does it point to internet.

The second one, please check if you have a configuration in 
/etc/apache2/sites-enalbed/ that might be missing for website to work properly.

Comment: When I ping to my configured domain, it points to my IP (the same I put on my VirtualHost). And I do not understand what do you mean with configurations on `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`. There is also a `000-default.conf` configuration, that it is on Apache by default. Could it affect to my configured domain?

Comment: by default configuration files should be placed here: /etc/apache2/sites-enalbed/

Answer (score 0):

by default configuration files should be placed here: /etc/apache2/sites-enalbed/  ; /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ - this directory should contain symlinks to original configration files. In my example:

```
VM:~$ ls -la /etc/apache2/sites-available/
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Lap  4 14:16 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Spa 27 19:44 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1332 Geg 20  2015 000-default.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6437 Geg 20  2015 default-ssl.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  264 Lap  4 14:16 snipeit.conf

VM:~$ ls -la /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Lap  4 14:16 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Spa 27 19:44 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   41 Lap  4 14:16 snipeit.conf -> /etc/apache2/sites-available/snipeit.conf
```

Comment: Yes, but they are placed there (on sites-enabled folder) when I use the command: `sudo a2ensite host1.com.conf`. If I use the command `ls -la /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` as you put above I get the same results as you (but on sites-enabled I also have a symlink to 000-default.conf). Can it be that another configuration (apart from the VirtualHost) on another file could disturb the normal behaviour of my VirtualHost?